# Remove existing admin menu Items in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, adminmenu

Looking for advice on where to place the `menu.xml` file in my child theme to remove menu items in Admin. Trying to clean it up after modules install extra items. Hopefully my syntax is correct.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
      <remove id="Mageplaza_Core::partners" />
      <remove id="Magento_Marketplace::partners" />
    </menu>
</config>
```

Currently located at `/public_html/app/design/frontend/My/childtheme/etc/adminhtml/menu.xml`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Seem that your menu xml is correct. However, **you need to create a custom module, not use custom theme**. And then, put your `menu.xml` under `etc/adminhtml/`.

Take a look: `vendor/magento/module-currency-symbol/etc/adminhtml/menu.xml`

```
<remove id="Magento_Backend::system_currency" />
```

Comment: ok, i'll look into creating a custom module. thanks @khoa